# Javascript include file and refresh every 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html, api, file-get-contents

I have 3 files i refer to them as:

```
     $nowplaying = file_get_contents("/api/static/nowplaying");
$dj = file_get_contents("/api/static/dj");
$listeners = file_get_contents("/api/static/listeners");
```

I want to call them in my php file inside div tags by using

```
'.$dj.'
'.$nowplaying.'
'.$listeners.'
```

but the contents of the files i am pulling update every 30 seconds so I need to refresh the data shown without refreshing the page. I'm thinking javascript jquery may be the one but i'm not too familiar with it.

Many thanks!

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [`setInterval()`](https://www.sitepoint.com/setinterval-example/)

Comment: This can be done by ajax. You can use jquery for sure - material to study here: http://api.jquery.com/?s=ajax

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get("/api/static/nowplaying",function(data){
        // Do something with data
    });
},30000);
```

with javascript kinda like

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
setInterval(function(){
    request.open('GET', '/api/static/nowplaying', true);
    request.send();
},30000)

request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        // Success!
        var data = request.responseText;
    } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think using jquery/JavaScript is what you are looking for and its pretty simple.   Just use the `setInterval()` method in JavaScript to have it repeatedly run a function on a schedule.  Since you're rather new to this I'll try to make a simple example.  The code below runs `updateDiv()` every 30 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js">
</script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>

var myVar
function updateDiv(){
    clearInterval(myVar);

    alert('your code should go here');

    myVar = setInterval("updateDiv()", 30000);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    myVar = setInterval("updateDiv()", 30000);
});
```

You can view this here: https://jsfiddle.net/jglazer63/h6q20dj9/1/

Comment: If you are going to clear and set the interval on each call, you would be better off just using `setTimeout` which fires only once. Meaning you don't need to clear, just set another timeout at the end. Also, all this would only need to be done if you couldn't finish processing before the next interval fires. If you have processing that takes longer than 30 seconds (the interval amount), then I would suggest refactoring it in some way.

Comment: Yeah still struggling with it.. Tried all of the above inside <div id="myVar"></div> and still nothing! :(

Comment: This is javascript.  It should go in between the <head> tags at the top of the page and should have a <script> and </script> before and after it.   Did you do that?  I'll add it for clarity....

Comment: I just need to include the stats.php file which is echoing the text :(

Comment: I updated the script above to include the link the jquery library (which you may have missed).   Now it will send you an alert every 30 seconds.  This is just a start.   You can try it on jsfille too.